# Как внести данные из qtableview в word?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, ms-word

Использую **QTableView** и **QSqlTableModel**. Необходимо данные из таблицы экспортировать в **word**. В вордовском документе должна быть сгенерирована такая же таблица со всеми данными. Как это можно сделать? Создал таблицу в ворде, используя:

```
QAxObject *ptable = pdoc->querySubObject("Tables");
ptable->querySubObject("Add(Range, NumRows, NumColumns, DefaultTableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior)",
                           pdoc->dynamicCall("Range()"), 10, 13, 1, 2);
```

Но как внести туда данные?

Comment: https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=00700-fe14caf2-d93e-45f6-814b-e2f4c1713d75

Comment: а как выровнять таблицу по центру?